# Changing the color based on it's value... take 2

Tags: javascript, html, css

Similar to my question last week [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799120/changing-the-color-based-on-its-value)

Again, I need to return the value green if it's true and red if it's false. The logic is right, it's just the styling that won't work, but I'm not sure why?

**JS**

```
    var getAcrobatInfo = function () {
        var noPDF = 'No PDF viewer installed';

        var getBrowserName = function () {
            return this.name = this.name || function () {
                var userAgent = navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "other";

                if (userAgent.indexOf("chrome") > -1) {
                    return "chrome";
                } else if (userAgent.indexOf("safari") > -1) {
                    return "safari";
                } else if (userAgent.indexOf("msie") > -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
                    return "ie";
                } else if (userAgent.indexOf("firefox") > -1) {
                    return "firefox";
                } else {
                    //return "ie";
                    return userAgent;
                }
            }();
        };

        var getActiveXObject = function (name) {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject(name);
            } catch (e) { }
        };

        var getNavigatorPlugin = function (name) {
            for (key in navigator.plugins) {
                var plugin = navigator.plugins[key];
                if (plugin.name == name) return plugin;
            }
        };

        var getPDFPlugin = function () {
            return this.plugin = this.plugin || function () {
                if (getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
                    return getActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF') || getActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
                } else {
                    return getNavigatorPlugin('Adobe Acrobat') || getNavigatorPlugin('Chrome PDF Viewer') || getNavigatorPlugin('WebKit built-in PDF');
                }
            }();
        };

        var isAcrobatInstalled = function () {
            return !!getPDFPlugin();
        };

        var getAcrobatVersion = function () {
            try {
                var plugin = getPDFPlugin();

                if (getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
                    var versions = plugin.GetVersions().split(',');
                    var latest = versions[0].split('=');
                    return parseFloat(latest[1]);
                }

                if (plugin.version) return parseInt(plugin.version);
                return plugin.name
            } catch (e) {
                return noPDF;
            }
        }

        return {Acrobat: isAcrobatInstalled()};
    };

    var info = getAcrobatInfo();
    var pdf = document.getElementById('acrobat');

    if (info.Acrobat) {
        pdf.classList.add('green');
        pdf.innerHTML = 'True';
    }
    else {
        pdf.classList.add('red');
        pdf.innerHTML = 'False';
    }    
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <tr>
        <td>PDF Viewer Enabled:</td>
        <td id="acrobat"></td>
   </tr>
```

**CSS**

```
#pdf.green {
  color: #33CC33;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#pdf.red {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: When you add the class `red/green` it wont work in this case because in the style sheet you have `#pdf.green` while your element has id `#acrobat`

Comment: @AmmarCSE ugh so simple, thank you :)